# Type trait test if template parameter is some instantiation of another template

Tags: c++, c++14, sfinae, type-traits, enable-if

Suppose in the following code the intention is to allow `T` in `Bar<T>` to be a `Foo<U>` for any `U`.

```
template<typename U>
class Foo { };

template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t< /*T is Foo<U> for any U*/>>
class Bar {
    // ...
};
```

Is there something I replace `/*T is Foo<U> for any U*/` with?

Comment: @Barry I see your edit but that extra condition was to avoid non-answering suggestions such as `template<typename U>class Bar{ using T=Foo<U>; }`

Comment: Why would anyone suggest that? That doesn't seem helpful to the question.

Comment: @Barry With your rep, people wouldn't second-guess what you actually wanted to ask, but I've learned to build distortion-resisting mechanisms into my questions.

Comment: You're more than welcome to roll back the edit if you think it counters the intent of the question - but I'd like to understand what kind of "non-answering suggestion" you're trying to avoid getting.

Comment: @Barry It doesn't counter the intent of the question -- in fact this is exactly how the question was originally drafted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a general trait to match for any specialization:

```
template <typename T, template <typename...> class Z>
struct is_specialization_of : std::false_type { };

template <typename... Args, template <typename....> class Z>
struct is_specialization_of<Z<Args...>, Z> : std::true_type { };
```

Which in your specific case would be:

```
is_specialization_of<T, Foo>::value // <== T is some kind of Foo
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a traits for that:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_foo : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_foo<Foo<T>> : std::true_type {};
```